# Function to add to Vector when only knowing base type

Tags: c++, inheritance

Ok, so I've been stuck on this all day. What I am trying to do is have a function that takes any derivative of a certain base class, and then adds it to a vector. I can't specify all of the derivatives, because I don't know them in advanced.

I know that this code is way off, but this is the simplest for of what I'm trying to do, because I'm not sure any of the other things I've tried (auto_ptr, casting, others) were even on the right track. Anyway:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
public:
    void go() {
        std::cout << "I am the base class" << std::endl;
    }
};

class DerA : public Base {
    void go() {
        std::cout << "I am the first derivative" << std::endl;
    }
};

class DerB : public Base {
    void go() {
        std::cout << "I am the second derivative" << std::endl;
    }
};

class UnrelatedClass {
public:
    std::vector<Base> vec;
    void add_to_vec(Base thing) {
        vec.push_back(thing);
    }
};

int main() {
    Base base;
    DerA dera;
    DerB derb;

    UnrelatedClass uc;
    uc.add_to_vec(base);
    uc.add_to_vec(dera);
    uc.add_to_vec(derb);

    for (auto thing : uc.vec) {
        thing.go();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this snippet, they get "sliced" (I think) and do not work:

```
I am the base class
I am the base class
I am the base class
```

I have tried using all kinds of things, but I'm really not sure what I'm doing and haven't been able to get it to work. I only recently started using c++ after a few years of python.

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: Using pointers to the base class would be better..

Comment: You should also look up the `virtual` keyword. And as @MarcoA. said, use pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is: you're storing complete objects instead of pointers to the base class.

If you intend to use a feature called "virtual polymorphism", you need to store your derivate objects as pointers to the base class.

Also: every method you intend to "forward" via a virtual table to the right derived class, must be marked as **virtual** in the base class.

I recommend [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) as a first-time reading.

And this is how you would do it in your example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void go() {
        std::cout << "I am the base class" << std::endl;
    }
};

class DerA : public Base {
    void go() {
        std::cout << "I am the first derivative" << std::endl;
    }
};

class DerB : public Base {
    void go() {
        std::cout << "I am the second derivative" << std::endl;
    }
};

class UnrelatedClass {
public:
    std::vector<Base*> vec;
    void add_to_vec(Base* thing) {
        vec.push_back(thing);
    }
};

int main() {
    Base base;
    DerA dera;
    DerB derb;

    UnrelatedClass uc;
    uc.add_to_vec(&base);
    uc.add_to_vec(&dera);
    uc.add_to_vec(&derb);

    for (auto thing : uc.vec) {
        thing->go();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/LJEz26

Comment: Thankyou! I had tried exactly this, however I was using "Base* base;" and "uc.add_to_vec(base);"

This little modification worked perfectly, now I will apply it to my actual project :D

Comment: And it worked great in my actual project :D 
Thank you so much :D

Comment: Although, I am still really confused as to how to convert this to unique_ptr's, as obviously I can't just drop them in. I'll keep trying to work it out, but perhaps if you could tell me what type of argument add_to_vec should take?

Comment: A unique_ptr is useful if you don't want to "leak memory". Keep in mind one thing with C++: everything you allocate with the "new" keyword (malloc in C) stays allocated until you explicitly free it. If you don't free it, it's called a memory leak because you "forget" about that space and can't use it anymore. unique_ptr and such allow you to automatically free that memory. In the case I posted there are no "new" or "malloc", when you go out of scope (a } is encountered in the easiest case), the objects above will be destroyed. Thus: no unique_ptr needed this time.

Comment: You can read more here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Answer (score 2):

First: function `go` in base class should be declared as `virtual`.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void go() {
        std::cout << "I am the base class" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Second: you should use pointers to base class (may be smart pointers, like `std::shared_ptr`/`std::unique_ptr`), not objects itself.

[example on ideone](http://ideone.com/Cz6ewX)